# Find the end of a ascending series with minimum query

Tags: algorithm, math, probability

Suppose there is an ascending positive integer series, and the intervals between any 2 adjacent integers follow a distribution, for example,

[5, 6, 11, 23, 24, 33, ...], where [image: f1], [image: f2]

*(Geometric distribution is the discrete version of exponential distribution)*

**Query(x)** could be made to check whether x is in this series. We already know **min**, **max**, **p**.

The problem is how to find the **end** (last x) of this series, with few **queries** as possible.

---

For example, min = 1, max = 10000, p = 0.15

The first idea I came with is **binary search**, however, since the interval of adjacent integers is not sure. I may select the 99th quantile, 30, as the maximum interval I believe, and during each search in the binary search, I would consecutively query 30 successive integers. In this case, the first batch of queries I made is (query(5000), query(5001),..., query(5030))

I think this method is somewhat inefficient(slow), and there is a small probability that interval exceed 30, which cannot guarantee the binary search can find the **end** correctly.

---

*PS:
It's my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. I'm sorry if I didn't state my question clear. Feel free to give me any suggestion and I will edit the question.*

Comment: After finding the `end`, perform a linear scan of next 2*interval numbers, to avoid finding wrong `end`.
However it seems like a tradeoff between finding correct `end` and using few `Query`.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this for nearly 3 days, I think that the best possible `Deterministic` way to figure out the end of the series, is using binary search (using 99th quantile as the maximum interval seems a reasonable choice).

Let's say you find out the `end` of the series using binary search, perform a check over next `2*interval_range` to make sure the `end` is correct or not.

Some `Probabilistic` methods can be employed, if we have information about how `x`'s are distributed in the range `[min,max]`.